# Material-UI: Adding Badge to a Tab in material-ui Tabbar (Tabs)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) [Tabs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) component with 5 Tab components as children. I would like to display a [Badge](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/badge) on the Tab. Badge would display unread items under each tab.

I have two versions of tab bar. One for desktop with icon and text and one for mobile containing just icon. How could I position Badge so that it places properly on both versions. Also Badge should be visible even if tab is not selected (if I set Badge as a child to a Tab it will be hidden when tab is not selected).

Comment: Maybe try putting it on your icons since they are always there.

Answer (score 57):

You can do it like this:

```
<Tab label={<Badge badgeContent={this.state.messageCount} color="primary">
    Messages
</Badge>} value="/messages" />
```

Comment: How can I put the word "Messages" before the badge? Thanks

Comment: @fredyjimenezrendon like this: `<Tab label={ Messages <Badge…`